# Which one is it: a4paper or paper=a4?

Tags: koma-script, document-classes, paper-size

I'm using XeLaTeX mostly, and I never know what to put into `\documentclass[]{}`.
Usually I use something like `\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}`. But I never know whether it's `a4paper` or `paper=a4`. I believe it has something to do the documentclass I'm using.

I need the paper selection for the KoMa-Classes, `scrartcl`, `scrbook`, `scrreprt`, as well as `g-brief2`, `dinbrief`, etc.

There is a plethora of sources on the internet, and while one source says `paper=a4`, another says `a4paper`. I need clarification on this one.

Comment: The syntax `paper=a4` is exclusive of the KoMa-Script classes (`scrartcl`, `scrbook`, `scrreprt` and `scrlettr`). No other class or package that I know accepts it. However, KoMa-Script classes recognize also `a4paper`.

Comment: @egreg sooo, which one should I use? Should I just use `a4paper` and be good with it, or should I use `paper=a4` when using KoMa-Script classes?

Comment: @polemon You can always happily use `a4paper`

Comment: Well `a4paper` works will almost every class including the KOMA-classes but gives there a rather long entry in the log file that you are doing the right thing. `paper=a4` is more silent. Choose what you like better. If you can't decide: throw a dice.

Comment: What on earth is ZeLaTeX? o.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The syntax `paper=a4` is exclusive of the KoMa-Script classes, that is, `scrartcl`, `scrbook`, `scrreprt` and `scrlettr`.

No other class or package that I know of accepts it: the only notable exception is, of course, the package `typearea`, which is part of the KoMa-Script bundle, to which the paper size options given to the KoMa-Script classes are deferred.

However, `typearea.sty` says also

```
\KOMA@DeclareStandardOption[typearea]{a4paper}{paper=a4}
```

so that `a4paper` as global option is recognized.

My preference would be to always use `a4paper`. While I see virtues in KoMa-Script approach, it's non standard.

Notice that `g-brief.cls` uses *only* A4 paper, while `dinbrief` uses it by default, so for these two classes you can avoid specifying the option. Also `scrlettr` uses A4 paper by default.